# How to merge Vertex Groups into one using Python?

Tags: python, scripting, vertices, vertex-groups

[image]

I have a list of vertex groups with similar names. I want to merge groups of vertices into 1 group. For example `jaw.001`, `jaw.002`, `jaw.003`, and so on, should be merged into one vertex group named `jaw`. I want to combine all weight data into one. How do I do this using Python?

Comment: What have you tried? Can you share your code?

Comment: @Psyonic https://pastebin.com/kPSRPWNK i need a smart way to do so